# GraphQL Update Children Object

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

```
const Photo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Photo',
  description: 'Photo',
  fields: () => ({
    upload: {type: GraphQLString},
    facebook: {type: GraphQLString},
    linkedin: {type: GraphQLString}
  })
});

const Account = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Account',
  description: 'Account',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
    created_on: {type: GraphQLDate},
    username: {type: GraphQLString},
    password: {type: GraphQLString},
    photo: {type: Photo},
  })
});

export default Account;
```

I have a mutation query to update record:

`mutation {
  updateAccountById(id: "587c84c713742bf421f3fa4e", update: {photo: {upload: "test1"}}) {
    photo {
      upload
      facebook
      linkedin
    }
  }
}`

Before:

```
photo{
 upload:"test1"
 facebook: "test2"
 linkedin: "test3"
}
```

After:
This will update photo attribute to

```
photo{
 upload:"test1"
}
```

Is there any way to update photo fields only ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The mutation:

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        updateAccountById:{
            type: Account,
            args: {
                id:{type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                update: {
                  type: new GraphQLInputObjectType({
                    name: 'update_account_byId',
                    fields: Account.getFields()
                  })
                }
            },
            resolve: function(rootValue, args) {
                let update = Object.assign({}, args.update);
                db.account.update({ _id: pmongo.ObjectId(args.id.toString())}, {$set: update},{multi:true});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the mutation? Looks like you are overwriting the `photo` object instead of just overwriting the `photo.upload` property.

Comment: @marktani i've update it in question

Comment: what is `db.account.update`?